# Add more columns to a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm using the Pandas function `pd.read_csv` to import a txt file delimited by `|`. The column header has 419 fields so it's calculating them all as such. Some of the rows have more than 419 columns though.

So How would I make the data frame malleable to increasing columns as it needs or just add X amount of columns to allow for more columns down the road.

Example:

How would I account for "F"?

```
A B C D E
A B C D E
A B C D E F
```

This is the error I'm receiving. I'm using python 3 in Jupyter notebook.

> ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 419 fields in line 7945, saw 424

This is the code I'm trying to use

```
data = pd.read_csv('filepath.txt', sep="|",skip_blank_lines=True, encoding = 'latin-1', header= None)
```

Comment: Why does the input file have unpredictable numbers of items in the rows?

Comment: There are extra deliminator in some rows which cause the rows to shift to the right. The biggest row is 480 columns. Part of the reason I'd like to import it as a dataframe is to see if there are any patterns. Rather of importing the individual rows and changing them individually.

Comment: @Xderic if you know the largest row just add the `names` param when you read: `names=range(0,480)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your setup, you won't know the number of columns until you've read *every single row*. That won't be efficient. One way is to read the data into a list of lists, appending an arbitrary number of `NaN` values as necessary. Then feed to the `pd.DataFrame` constructor.

Here's an example:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
import numpy as np

x = StringIO("""A|B|C|D|E
A|B|C|D|E
A|B|C|D|E|F""")

# replace x with open('file.csv', 'r')
with x as fin:
    data = list(csv.reader(fin, delimiter='|'))

num = max(map(len, data))
data = [i+[np.nan]*(num-len(i)) for i in data]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

   0  1  2  3  4    5
0  A  B  C  D  E  NaN
1  A  B  C  D  E  NaN
2  A  B  C  D  E    F
```

Comment: I wonder, is it horribly inefficient to read it as a `.csv` with the separator as `'\n'` and then just `df[0].str.split('|', expand=True)`?

Comment: @ALollz, That should work, but in my experience the Pandas `str` accessor is poor versus a list comprehension. But feel free to post that solution, it seems viable.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using pure pandas:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = pd.read_csv('filepath.txt', sep="|",skip_blank_lines=True, encoding = 'latin-1', header= None)
>>> data
             0
0    A B C D E
1    A B C D E
2  A B C D E F
```

We're able to split each row on whitespace since the delimiter we specified above doesn't exist (AFAIK) in the dataset and therefore creates just one column:

```
>>> s = data[0].apply(lambda x: x.split())
>>> s
0       [A, B, C, D, E]
1       [A, B, C, D, E]
2    [A, B, C, D, E, F]
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Iterate across the list in each row, creating a dictionary column: value mapping for later use with `pd.DataFrame` constructor:

```
>>> s = s.apply(lambda x: {'col_' + str(i): v for i, v in enumerate(x)})
>>> s
0    {'col_0': 'A', 'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'C', 'co...
1    {'col_0': 'A', 'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'C', 'co...
2    {'col_0': 'A', 'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'C', 'co...
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

We'll use the `pd.DataFrame.from_records` method, which can take data of the following format:

```
>>> s = s.values.tolist()
>>> s
[{'col_0': 'A', 'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'C', 'col_3': 'D', 'col_4': 'E'}, {'col_0': 'A', 'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'C', 'col_3': 'D', 'col_4': 'E'}, {'col_0': 'A', 'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'C', 'col_3': 'D', 'col_4': 'E', 'col_5': 'F'}]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(s)
>>> df
  col_0 col_1 col_2 col_3 col_4 col_5
0     A     B     C     D     E   NaN
1     A     B     C     D     E   NaN
2     A     B     C     D     E     F
```

Comment: Or `data[0].str.split()` ?